# what tool can I use to load test concurrent users accessing an API with unique input parameters

Tags: load

I want to load test a a web application with 100 users all hitting an API at the same time

The API executes a sproc, but each user's request will be calling the sproc with unique input parameters.

So you are hitting the same sproc but accessing different data in the database. Which perf tool would enable me to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Jmeter might be helpful for you though it depends on your use case. This may be helpful [jmeter parameterization](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide)